# shell insert new line using sed command failing in jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to insert new line in YAML file using sed command via Jenkins. It is working locally when try via command line (`cmder`)

YAML file

```
access_url: http://abc
db-url: oracle_path
```

Jenkins file command to add new line

```
sh ''' sed -i "/access_url: http://abc$/a \  user_id: '6100539'" ${file} '''
```

Jenkin build failure right after start up without any error after introduce above line.

Expected result after execution:

```
access_url: http://abc
  user_id: '6100539'
db-url: oracle_path
```

But when I tried below command locally with cmder it gives expected result above

```
sed -i "/access_url: http://abc$/a \  user_id: '6100539'" file
```

Error in Jenkins:

```
GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 459: unexpected char: '\' @ line 459, column 119.
   http://abc$/a \  user_id
                                 ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:320)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Please post the error message for better support.

Comment: @Vijay Sorry I missed the console error in Jenkins, Now added to the question. It looks like `\ ` which was used to escape leading spaces causing trouble.

Comment: Adding extra `\ ` done the job